# Structure of Hochschild homology (under shuffle product) for truncated polynomial algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field with an arbitrary characteristic $\mathrm{char}(k)$. I am trying to determine the Hochschild homology $\mathrm{HH}_\ast(A)$, where $A=k[x]/(x^n)$ is the truncated polynomial algebra with some $n>1$. Since $A$ is commutative, the shuffle product${}^{1}$ induces a structure of a graded commutative $k$-algebra on $\mathrm{HH}_\ast(A)$, so I would like to consider  $\mathrm{HH}_\ast(A)$ with this structure on it.

I expect that the result may depend on divisibility of $n$ by $\mathrm{char}(k)$, but I still do not see the explicit simple argument how to get the full description of this algebra. I will be grateful for any hint or suggestion.

${}^{1}$ The shuffle product is defined on the chain level by:
$$(a_0\otimes a_1\otimes...\otimes a_p)\cdot (a_0'\otimes a_{p+1}\otimes ... a_{p+q})=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_{p,q}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_0a_0'\otimes a_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes...\otimes a_{\sigma^{-1}(p+q)}.$$

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3210) gives a neat description of Hochschild *cohomology* of a hypersurface. At the moment I cannot see if one can use this in your favour, though.

Comment: You can read the [notes](https://irma.math.unistra.fr/~kassel/Kassel-ICTPnotes2004.pdf) by C. Kassel to the ICTP (2004), top of page 18.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=k[x]/(x^n)$, where $k$ is a commutative ring and $n\geq 2$.  Let $B=A\otimes_k A$ be the enveloping algebra. Since  $A$ is free as a $k$-module, we know that $HH_*(A)=\mathsf{Tor}_*^B(A,A)$.

Note that $B=k[y,z]/(y^n, z^n)$ where $y=x\otimes 1$ and $z=1\otimes x$. The $B$-bimodule structure of $A$ is given by $y1_A=x=1_Az$.

Let $q\in B$ be the sum of the monomials of total degree $n-1$, we have $q(y-z)=y^n-z^n=0$. Claim: the following complex is a resolution of $A$ by free $A$-bimodules of rank one
$$\cdots \stackrel{u}{\longrightarrow} B\stackrel{v}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{u}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{v}\longrightarrow B \longrightarrow A\longrightarrow 0$$
where $v(1)=y-z$ and $u(1)=q$. The last morphism maps $1$ to $1$ (so $y$ and $z$ are mapped to $x$).

If $f(y-z)=0$, there are no monomials of $f$ of total degree $<n-1$. Moreover the coefficients of the monomials of total degree $\geq n-1$ are equal. Note that $y^iq=qz^i$ is the sum of the monomials of total degree $n-1+i$. Thus $f$ is a multiple of $q$, that is $\mathsf{Ker} v \subset \mathsf{Im} u$.

The morphism $u:B/(y-z)\to B$ is injective, since the basis of $B/(y-z)$ has image $\{q, qy, \dots, qy^{n-1}\}$ which is a free family. Moreover the last surjective morphism has kernel $\mathsf{Im}v$.

Observe that $A\otimes_{A\otimes A}B= A$ through $1\otimes y \mapsto x$ and  $1\otimes z \mapsto x$. We obtain then the following complex computing $HH_*(A)$
$$ \cdots \stackrel{nx^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} A\stackrel{0}{\longrightarrow} A \stackrel{nx^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} A \stackrel{0}\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow 0.$$
Thus $HH_0(A)=A$ as expected, and
$$HH_{\mathsf{odd}}(A)=k\oplus kx \oplus \cdots \oplus kx^{n-2} \oplus (k/nk) x^{n-1}$$
$$HH_{\mathsf{even}>0}(A)= k\oplus kx \oplus \cdots \oplus kx^{n-2} \oplus ({}_nk) x^{n-1} \ \mathsf{ where }\  {}_nk=\mathsf{Ker} k \stackrel{n}{\longrightarrow} k.$$
For a field $k$ which characteristic does not divide $n$
$$HH_0(A)= k^n \mbox{ and } HH_{*>0}(A)=k^{n-1},$$
while if the characteristic divides $n$ we have
$$HH_*(A)=k^n.$$